# Set value of an array based on result from other arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so I have 3 arrays

lets say:

```
storedKeys = {"h","e","l","l","o"}
randomKeys = {2,1,5,4,3}
keyValues = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
```

What I want to do is set the values of a 4th array (codedValues)
to the values of keyValues based on randomKeys

so codedValues[0] = "c" - Because index 0 of randomKeys is 2 and the 3rd value in keyValues is "c".

Preferably I'd like to do this in a loop,  but I can figure that out on my own if you can help figure out  how to  set at least the first index to the right value! :D

I've tried different loopings  but can't wrap my head around it. 
Having cryptography later this semester but want to get a head start and I'm not very familiar with programming yet, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: The code I ended up using was:

```
for (int i = 0; i < storedKeys.length; i++) {
    codedValues[i] = keyValues[randomKeys[i]];
}
```

Comment: please try to solve it on your own! it's not hard at all

Comment: @PhilippSander It may not be, but I've struggled for a while now  and my classmates are of no help so I had to ask here. Any help if not a complete solution is greatly appreciated

Comment: The value of one array can be the index of another array. Try to use this fact.

Comment: we won't be doing your homework...

Comment: @thecoder Yes, but I've only done this with 2 arrays in a for loop before. No clue how to do with 3, may be me being very unexperienced with programming. Just finished my first semester at the University.

Comment: Please add your best attempt to code this. So we can know what to give you as a hint.

Comment: "so codedValues[0] = "c" - Because index 0 of randomKeys is 2 and the 3rd value in keyValues is "c"" - so your index into keyValues is the value of randomKeys at the index you are looping over ... for example `codedValues[i]` => you get the index to use for keyValues from `randomKeys[i]` ... Sidenote: Make sure to check boundaries! (what if randomKeys contains value "100" but keyValues has only 5 entries?)

Comment: @Fildor I was very close to the solution. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not so hard you can do it in this way :

generates random keys based on `randomKeys[]` array values and set it to `codedValues[]` array

it will be like :

```
codedValues[0] = keyValues[randomKeys[0]];
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a for loop, that is correct, to get the value to be inserted in you codedValues array, you will have to iterate your randomKeys array, and for each element (an index ) you access the keyValues array at that position and get the value, with that value in hand you add it to your codedValues array and move on .

Answer (score 1):

run a loop, then set codedvalue array value using below code .

```
    int i=0;
    while(i<sizeOfarray){
       codedvalue[i] = keyvalue[randomKey[i]];
       i++;
    }
```